# A lot of instances HttpClient with proxy

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-leaks, httpclient

I can't understand, which is the right way to use HttpClient in different threads with different handlers? I need that every my thread working with HttpClient with different proxy in one time (about 300 threads). I have read a lot of pages - I should use single HttpClient, without creating new instances. But how can I use it with different httpclienthandlers?

Now I create new instances with every new proxy and it rises memory leak. Using, Dispose not help... Simple example:

```
public void start_parallel()
    {
        List<int> start = new List<int>();
        int gg = 0;
        while (gg != 30000)
        {
            gg += 1;
            start.Add(gg);
        }
        while (true)
        {


            Parallel.ForEach(start, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 300 }, (s) => worker(s));
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            GC.Collect();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        
    }

public void worker(int i)
{
      using (var http_client = new HttpClient(handler)
      {
           await http_client.PostAsync(url, data);
      };
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It's good to see that you have a CPU core with 300 processors. Most of us only have about 4 or 8 cores to play with so any more that `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8` doesn't help us.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a `HttpClientFactory` instead of manually create `HttpClient` instances.
It solves most issues with `HttpClient`. quoting the docs:

> As a first issue, while this class is disposable, using it with the using statement is not the best choice because even when you dispose HttpClient object, the underlying socket is not immediately released and can cause a serious issue named ‘sockets exhaustion’. For more information about this issue, see You're using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software blog post.
>
> [...]
>
> But there’s a second issue with HttpClient that you can have when you use it as singleton or static object. In this case, a singleton or static HttpClient doesn't respect DNS changes, as explained in this issue at the .NET Core GitHub repo.

More at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

And to answer your question: you made a mistake described in point one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not really understand the difference between creating HttpClient with Factory or not. If i'll use Factory, they will disposed?

Comment: The simple answer no, but instead of creating a lot of them, they will be taken from the pool. So HttpClientFactory creates only a few instances and then share it. Moreover when the pool can reduce it will dispose of redundant instances.